# HighMaps: Using multi-valued mapData identifier in joinBy option

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

Consider that map of India geo json is selected for creating maps. If I use an identifier like "region" in joinBy option which is multi-valued i.e. many states have the same region, what would be displayed on the map?

http://jsfiddle.net/amrutaJgtp/2r2nfz97/3/

In the above fiddle, I've given region as joinBy

```
data: data,
mapData: Highcharts.maps['countries/in/in-all'],
joinBy: 'region',
name: 'Random data',
```

As seen in the output, the map shown is incorrect. What is the reason for this? Should the identifier used for joinBy option be unique to the mapData (1:1 relationship between mapData and data)?

Answer (score 1):

As per my analysis your wrote wrong field in

```
  joinBy : 'region'
```

it should be

```
joinBy: 'hc-key'
```

Here is fiddle to check what i changed for you.hope this will help you.

```
jsfiddle.net/2r2nfz97/4/
```

try updated fiddle

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12192142)

Comment: @OlivierDeMeulder : thanks for suggestion, i have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that, yes, the relationship should be between mapData and data, as you surmised. You could either:

1. Take a subsection of the mapData that's relevant for only the areas you want to show in your map and add the "region" variable (I've done this for parts of the U.S. where I only want to show certain states).
2. Try modifying what you have to resemble the "category map" in the Highcharts demo page (see http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/category-map). It looks like what they're doing here is including lists of countries/states within different series, which make up the different regions.

I hope this information is helpful for you!